# Why am I getting the output 'None'?

Tags: python-3.x

My code (rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock)is getting the right inputs but my function is only working sometimes, other times it gives me the output 'None'. Why is this happening?

I tried messing with the dictionaries and using different ways to get an output (like print and return) but it still sometimes gives me the output 'None' and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
import random
Num1 = random.randint(1,2) 

def CPU():
    return random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"])
def User_Choice():
    User_Choice = input("What do you choose, rock, paper, scissors, lizard or spock?")
    User_Choice = User_Choice.lower()
    while User_Choice not in ["rock","paper","scissors","lizard","spock"]:
        User_Choice = input("That is not an option, please try again")
        User_Choice = User_Choice.lower()

    return User_Choice
def Who_Wins(CPU_Choice,User_Choice1):
    #put in CPU Choice first
    if CPU_Choice == User_Choice1:
        return("It was a draw, tension among the onlookers rises")
    elif Num1 == 1:
        Who_Wins1 = {
                #The Zentharian Wins
                ("scissors","paper"):"You lose, The Zentharian chose scissors which cut up your paper",
                ("paper","rock"):"You lose, The Zentharian chose paper which covered your rock",
                ("rock","lizard"):"You lose, The Zentharian chose rock which crushed your lizard",
                ("lizard","spock"): "You lose, The Zentharian chose lizard which poisoned spock",
                ("spock","scissors"): "You lose, The Zentharian chose spock who smashed your scissors",
                #Player Win
                ("scissors","lizard"): "You Win, your scissors decapitated the Zentharians's lizard",
                ("lizard","paper"): "You win, your lizard ate the Zentharians's paper",
                ("paper","spock"): "You win, your paper disproved the Zentharians's spock",
                ("spock","rock"): "You win, your spock vaporized the Zentharians's rock",
                ("rock","scissors"): "You win, your rock crushed the Zentharians's scissors"
                }
        if (CPU_Choice,User_Choice1) in Who_Wins1:
            return Who_Wins1.get((CPU_Choice,User_Choice1),"no value returned")
    elif Num1 == 2:
        Who_Wins2 = {
                #The AI Wins
                ("scissors","paper"):"You lose, The AI chose scissors which cut up your paper",
                ("paper","rock"):"You lose, The AI chose paper which covered your rock",
                ("rock","lizard"):"You lose, The AI chose rock which crushed your lizard",
                ("lizard","spock"): "You lose, The AI chose lizard which poisoned spock",
                ("spock","scissors"): "You lose, The AI chose spock who smashed your scissors",
                #Player Win
                ("scissors","lizard"): "You Win, your scissors decapitated the AI's lizard",
                ("lizard","paper"): "You win, your lizard ate the AI's paper",
                ("paper","spock"): "You win, your paper disproved the AI's spock",
                ("spock","rock"): "You win, spock vaporized the AI's rock",
                ("rock","scissors"): "You win, your rock crushed the AI's scissors"
                }
        if (CPU_Choice,User_Choice1) in Who_Wins2:
            return Who_Wins2.get((CPU_Choice,User_Choice1),"no value returned")
    else:
        return "at least you know what the error is now"

Who_Against()
CPU_Choice = CPU()
User_Choice1 = input("Choose rock, paper, scissors, lizard or spock ")
Winner = Who_Wins(CPU_Choice,User_Choice1)
print(Winner)
```

Comment: Please attach your code as formatted text and not as image. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) why.

Comment: Where do you define `Num1`? Think what would happen if `Num1` isn't 1 nor 2

Comment: I have set a print statement at the bottom of the code to print out Num1 so I can see that it is right. Num1 is set at the almost top and it is just random.rantint(1,2)

Comment: Can you attach the input & output?

Comment: Do you want me to just attach the whole code?

Comment: I don't need the full code, only Minimal, Reproducible Example. It would be easier to find your problem if you showed the input that caused the unexpected result

Comment: what do you mean by 'input that caused the unexpected result'?

Comment: "_but it still sometimes gives me the output 'None'_" When does it gives you `None`? What is the input & output of such case?

Comment: I don't really know, even if I just type 'rock' over and over it will still give me varied answers(e.g. you win, you lose as intended or 'none')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is `None` when there isn't `(CPU_Choice,User_Choice1)` in the dictionaries. When that happens, it doesn't enter the `if` and there isn't any `else` part for such case. As a result it reaches to the end of the function and returns `None`.

For example, you have this tuple in your dictionaries: `("rock","lizard")`.

But what happens when it is the other way around and `User_Choice1` is `'rock'` and `CPU_Choice` is `'lizard'`?

---

If you removed the `if` and have this

```
            return Who_Wins2.get((CPU_Choice,User_Choice1),"no value returned")
```

or this

```
            return Who_Wins1.get((CPU_Choice,User_Choice1),"no value returned")
```

returned without it, you would get the `'no value returned'` for such undefined cases

---

##### Edit:

Instead of the code duplication, you might want to use formatted string:

```
def Who_Wins(CPU_Choice,User_Choice1):
    if CPU_Choice == User_Choice1:
        return("It was a draw, tension among the onlookers rises")
    else:
        wins = {'cpu': ('lose', 'The %s chose', 'your'),
                'user': ('win', 'your', "the %s's"),
        }
        machine = ['Zentharian', 'AI'][Num1 -1]

        Who_Wins1 = {
                ("scissors","paper"):"scissors which cut up %s paper",
                ("paper","rock"):"paper which covered %s rock",
                ("rock","lizard"):"rock which crushed %s lizard",
                ("lizard","spock"): "lizard which poisoned %s spock",
                ("spock","scissors"): "spock who smashed %s scissors",
                ("scissors","lizard"): "scissors decapitated %s lizard",
                ("lizard","paper"): "lizard ate %s paper",
                ("paper","spock"): "paper disproved %s spock",
                ("spock","rock"): "spock vaporized %s rock",
                ("rock","scissors"): "rock crushed %s scissors"
                }
        answer = 'You %s, %s '
        cpu_win = (CPU_Choice,User_Choice1)            
        winner = 'user'
        if cpu_win in Who_Wins1:
            winner = 'cpu'
            answer += Who_Wins1[cpu_win]
        else:
            answer += Who_Wins1[cpu_win[::-1]]
        return answer % wins[winner] % machine
```

---

You should also replace this:

```
User_Choice1 = input("Choose rock, paper, scissors, lizard or spock ")
```

with:

```
User_Choice1 = User_Choice()
```

Comment: Oh I think I get it, my dictionary doesn't have every possible outcome in it so there is no value to return. Thank you so much.

Comment: I edited my answer. please look at the 'edit'

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand that because I'm not advanced enough, and instead of using code I don't understand (Though I can tell that its a way better way of doing it) I would prefer to use simpler code that I understand and can learn from.

Comment: I understand that but keep in mind that it is not much more complicated than the code you posted. It is using lists, tuples and dictionaries just like the code you provided did. I only added formatted string which isn't complicated. If you want you can learn more about it [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-string-interpolation-with-the-percent-operator/)